# Being traveller in terminal 2 can I go to terminal 1 or 3 for shopping in duty free shop?

Tags: transit, layovers, airport-security, dxb

I will travel in flydubai and will have around 8 hours layover time in hand at terminal 2. Can I go to terminal 1 or 3 to duty free shop? What about getting visa also to go to buy some gold jewellery outside? Thanx.
Arefin.

Comment: Those are two very different questions, and should be asked as such. For the second one, you'll also need to tell us your nationality

Answer (score 2):

You cannot go to Terminal 1 or 3 from Terminal 2 without a boarding pass for a departure flight from either of those terminals.

Regarding your second question, visa on arrival depends on your citizenship. You can see the list of countries eligible for visa on arrival [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates#Visa_on_arrival).